# Override template engine for Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have read that you can override the Kendo UI templating engine and supply a third party one (such as JS Render), see [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/11-08-26/kendo_ui_templates_faster_than_a_speeding_resig)

Specifically, I am using a Grid and I want to add a template to a cell, so my column definition would look something like:

```
columns: [{template: "<ul>{{for xxx}}<li>{{:yyy}}</li>{{/for}}</ul>"]
```

How do you replace the kendo templating engine with something like JSRender?

Comment: Maybe you can do it but do you need doing it? From your template there is nothing that you cannot do with KendoUI templates, why do not stay with it and do not add extra complexity and more dependencies?

Comment: I'm creating a prototype where I am abstracting the Kendo UI grid behind a Polymer/xtag web component. I don't want any dependencies on Kendo in my HTML that consumes the component.

Comment: The component has markup for the column definitions, including a template for one of the columns (written in js render, but could be any templating engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik support have come back with an answer - though I've not tried it yet. Rather than specify the  template as a string, you can provide a function that returns the rendered HTML, therefore you can use JSRender in that function.